# Expand a HTML table with jQuery dependent on an intendation string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

**Introduction:**

in my department, a colleague and me trying to build a inventory control system based on the Django Framework. Basically, most of the stuff is working. But at the moment, we have some problems with jQuery.
Imagine, we have some devices in our database, e.g. a mobilephone, of which we want to get a detailed view of all components. Each of this devices have some subcomponents (e.g. a motherboard), which can also have subcomponents (e.g. CPU, RAM,...).


**Explanation:**

The django implementation (in the HTML file) of the methods, which provides the nessecary data, looks like the following:

```
        {% for module in submodels %}
            <p>
                {{ module.intentation }} || submodules: {{ module.has_subs }} || {{ module.object }} 
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
```

If the module has a submodule, the method `has_subs` returns a true.
The intentation of a module itself is listed in the string, which the method `intentation` returns.

In this case, we want to dynamically expand a HTML table concerning on the submodules. The following graphic shows what we are thinking about.

```
>   |   1.1     |   OLED
V   |   1.2     |   Motherboard
    |   1.2.1   |   CPU
    |   1.2.2   |   RAM
>   |   1.3     |   Battery
>   |   1.4     |   Motion Sensor
```

If the flag `has_subs` of a modul is TRUE, all the subordinated (which are listed in the returned String of the method `intentation`) modules should expand. For example: By clicking on the Motherboard (1.2), all submodules with the `intentation` of 1.2.x should expand. (The data structure of the intentation of a module has following zeros. E.g. for the OLED:
1.1.0.0, Motherboard: 1.2.0.0, CPU: 1.2.1.0, RAM: 1.2.2.0, ...) 


**Question:**

How could we implement this functionality with jQuery to expand the table? We though about a jquery function, which parses the intentation Strings and the `has_subs` value.

We also would like to implement the two buttons "Close all" and "Expand all".

Thanks for any help,

regards matthieu

Answer (score 0):

You would want a  tag such as:

```
{% if module.has_subs %} 
    <p class ="with-subs-p">
        Module Name
    </p>
    <div class="with-subs-d">
        # Print each of the subs in whatever format you like
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>Module Name</p>
...
```

That's all for the HTML and tags, CSS/formatting also up to you.

The JQuery is relatively simple also:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $(".with-subs-d").hide();
  $(".with-subs-p").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".with-subs-d").slideToggle(600);
  });
});
```

Comment: For clarity could you explain why? On that note, simply out of interest, what is "intendation?"